# Ignore directory in SVN without affecting svn:ignore on server?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I know about the svn:ignore property, but that doesn't solve my problem.

I have a source directory.  I want to create a directory inside it, called "build" that I will build inside.  I don't want to put "build" in svn:ignore because other people using the same repository don't need it ignored, and I may want to have different names for this.

The general problem is this:

Given a working copy of a subversion directory, I want to make a subdirectory that will be ignored by svn without modifying anything on the server.  If I could make a directory and stick an empty ".svn_ignore_this_directory" file inside it or something, that would be awesome.  I think in git it would be something like making a .gitignore file with just "." in it, but maybe that's not right.  Can svn do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `.subversion` file that [defines the configuration of your local machine](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html) (the location of this file will depend on your OS).  Inside that file, use the `global-ignores` option to configure files or folders that you want your local Subversion to ignore.  Changes made to this file will only affect your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've understood what you want to achieve, but:

- If you want svn to ignore that folder simply don't version it. Depending on the client you're using you can hide unversioned files/folders from the commit list.
- If other people don't need it ignored, they need it versioned? if that is true, then it has no sense for you to have it ignored.

Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: doesn't address what I'm looking for.  I want to silence the " ?    foobar" lines from svn status