# Ignore specific directories or files without using svn:ignore

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For some reason nobody ever has set up decent `svn:ignore` properties in our repository, and when I asked about it the response was "nobody has complained about that before, can't you just leave 'unversioned items' unchecked?" (We pretty much globally use TortoiseSVN).

I'm new to the team, so I want to set up some local ignore lists instead of making changes to the repository willy-nilly.

I know about the global ignore list, but [the global ignore list does not accept specific paths](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html), only simple one-level file patterns. I read a [question about a local ignore list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/895548/1390430) but that question is actually not asking about "ignoring" unversioned files, but actually is asking about blocking commits on specific versioned files. I read another [question about ignoring a directory locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10325240/1390430) like I want to do, but the accepted answer on that question uses the global ignore list, which doesn't work for me due to not being able to specify specific paths within my working copy.

I can set some `svn:ignore` properties locally, but directories cannot be added to changelists (as recommended in the question above for avoiding commits of versioned files), so I risk accidentally committing those changes.

Is there a way to locally ignore specific unversioned directories or files in my working copy tree, without using `svn:ignore`?

---

**Update:** The current top answer gets me *very* close to what I want. It allows me to filter out arbitrary files in either the "check for modifications" or the "commit" dialogs. However, if I want to include *directory* changes (i.e. changes to the versioned properties of a directory) then TortoiseSVN will also include all files under the directory automatically (i.e. I cannot both include a directory in the list, *and* filter out files under the directory).

Answer (score 5):

I could not a find a seamless way to accomplish what you're looking for, but I did find an option that *might* suit your needs, considering that this is something you want solely for your local machine.

It's possible to manually invoke the TortoiseSVN Commit dialog, providing the paths for it to search for files to commit, like this:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /pathfile:"<a file containing paths>"
```

So, since you know which directories & files you want to ignore, you could provide a paths file containing only those directories & files you wish to commit.

Bear in mind that the path file must be in UTF-16 (little-endian) encoding, *without* the BOM.  Paths are separated by new line characters.  You can create such a valid paths file (in C#), like this:

```
string[] paths = { @"c:\code\1\dir1", @"c:\code\1\dir2", @"c:\code\1\dir3\file1.txt" };
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\pathslist.txt", string.Join("\n", paths), encoding);
```

In my experimentation with the paths, both directory and file paths are supported, but not wildcards, so any filtering would need to be done at the time you produce the paths file.

There are a couple of additional command line options for `TortoiseProc /command:commit`, which you can find [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics).

The same method will work for "Check for modifications", substituting `/command:repostatus` in place of `/command:commit`. In summary:

1. Create a script that grabs all file names of interest
2. Filter out all file names that are not interesting (possibly from an "ignore file" somewhere on your machine).
3. Write the list of files in UTF-16 LE format (without BOM).
4. Call TortoiseProc with a `/pathfile` argument specifying the file list and `/command` of either repostatus or commit.
5. Optionally, delete the file list.

---

**Optional - Integrating with "Commit" using a hook script**

As an aside, I did find one path of "integration" by making use of the TortoiseSVN Hook Script options in Settings.  It still uses the TortoiseProc procedure above, but additionally provides a way to still make use of the TortoiseSVN Commit context menu (with one quirk).

The specific language you use for the hook script is not important, only that it be able to process command line arguments and return an exit code.  From the documentation ([here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)):

> This could be a batch file, an executable file or any other file
>   which has a valid windows file association, e.g. a perl script.

For this example, I used C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Process the three command-line arguments
    string PATH = args[0]
        , MESSAGEFILE = args[1]
        , CWD = args[2];

    const string tortoiseProcPath = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe";
    const string someArgForOurUse = @"/2E040D90-E3AD-4AC5-AA46-E6D9F1034E55";
    const string wantedPathsFile = @"C:\temp\svn_paths_list.txt";

    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

    System.Diagnostics.Process parentProc = ParentProcessUtilities.GetParentProcess();

    // If the parent process isn't what is expected or it has the proprietary argument then exit.
    if ((parentProc == null) || (!parentProc.MainModule.FileName.Equals(tortoiseProcPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        || GetProcessCommandLine(parentProc.Id).Contains(someArgForOurUse))
        return;

    // Read all selected path from passed-in the temp file
    // Each line contains a file/directory selected in Explorer
    string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(PATH);
    IEnumerable<string> wantedPaths = GetWantedPaths(fileLines);

    UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(wantedPathsFile, string.Join("\n", wantedPaths), encoding);

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tortoiseProcPath, "/command:commit /pathfile:\"" + wantedPathsFile + "\" " + someArgForOurUse);

    Console.Error.WriteLine("Don't worry.  Everything will be ok.");
    Environment.Exit(1);
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetWantedPaths(string[] selectedPaths)
{
    // Do whatever you want here to filter directories and files
    return selectedPaths;
}

// Add System.Management reference
private static string GetProcessCommandLine(int processId)
{
    System.Management.SelectQuery wmiQuery = new System.Management.SelectQuery("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId.ToString());
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);

    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
        return obj["CommandLine"].ToString();
    return null;
}
```

For brevity's sake, `ParentProcessUtilities.GetParentProcess`, which I used from another SO post, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346055/1197605).

**Explanation:**

The PATH input argument points to a temp file which contains all of the directories and files selected in Explorer.  From this, you can build your list of wanted paths.  When the list is constructed and written to file, we then relaunch TortoiseProc, passing the new file as an argument, as well as a proprietary argument, which can be used for tracking.

At the end, we return an exit code other than 0, which prevents the original TortoiseSVN Commit window from appearing, with one caveat.  An "error" dialog will appear, displaying the message written to stderr; the quirk of which I was speaking.  One of the most important parts of this code is checking the parent process for the proprietary argument before actually doing all of this work.  This check prevents the hook from running an infinite number of times, because when TortoiseProc is relaunched by the above code, the hook script will be triggered again and, subsequently, call this code again.

I also looked into whether or not the originally passed-in PATH file's contents could just be altered in place, but it cannot.  It is unfortunately just a file that TortoiseSVN outputs explicitly for the purpose of the hook script, then deletes it.  Perhaps this could be a future feature.

Comment: This seems promising, if I build the path list on the fly via script, I could keep a separate ignore file for the script to use to exclude specific paths. I'd be interested to hear how this could  integrate with a commit hook.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it some more my main problem was with the "check for modifications" dialog. I may try exploring this solution some for that area but it looks like it would take some custom script to launch the dialog, since there do not appear to be any hooks for "check for modifications".

Comment: Correct, there is not a way to hook "check for modiciations," as can be done with "commit."  However, if you do want to explore the custom script route, you can replace "/command:commit" with "/command:repostatus" to display "check for modiciations."  Both commands make use of the /pathfile argument to determine which files to display.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work, although it is rather clunky. I tested with a manually created file, but I plan to create a script to build a file list and filter out any files or directories in a master "ignore file" stored off somewhere, before calling "commit" or "repostatus".

Comment: Rats, I did find one problem: I cannot see any way to include directory property changes in the dialog, without also including all files under the directory. But it still gets me very close! It's worth the bounty anyway, but I'm going to leave the question unanswered for now, hoping to find a way to manage the directory property changes *and* filter out unwanted files under the directory.

Comment: I see what you mean about the recursion.  I found an overkill way (a registry hack) to stop the recursion on unversioned directories, but no luck for versioned directories.